# Gaussian Process predictive gradient with GPML

Tags: matlab, gaussian-process

Given a Gaussian Process $f(x) = \mathcal{GP}\big( m(x), k(x,x') \big)$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, I would like to calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right]$; that is, the $i^\mathrm{th}$ coordinate of $\mathrm{grad} f$.

For short, I use the notation $\partial_i \bullet$ for the $i^\mathrm{th}$ gradient coordinate below. Following the GPML book by Rasmussen and Williams p.16, I think this can be done as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \partial_i f_*\ \big| X, f, X_* \right] 
  = \partial_i \mathbb{E}\left[ f_*\ \big| X, f, X_* \right] 
  = \partial_i K(X_*, X) K(X,X)^{-1} f
$$
where $X$ are coordinates with known function values $f$, $X_*$ is a matrix of coordinates with unknown function values $f_*$, and we want the $i^\mathrm{th}$ coordinate of the gradient at these points $\partial_i f_*$.

In short, we simply need the derivative of the covariance function with respect to that coordinate. For example with the (isotropic) squared-exponential covariance:
$$
\partial_i k_\mathrm{SE}(x,x') 
  = \partial_i k_\mathrm{SE}(r = \|x -x'\|_2) 
  = -\frac{2r (x_i - x_i')}{L^2}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2L^2}\right)
$$

I was able to program this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and it seems likely that there would be a way to compute this with the GPML toolbox already. The help for `covFunctions` indicates that the second output `dK` is the "*linear directional derivative function*", which can apparently be called with `dK(Q)`; but I am not sure what this means, or how to use it. Hence my questions:

**Q1.** Is it correct that the gradient of a GP with respect to its *variables* (not its parameters, as often found elsewhere in the context of GP training) is simply obtained as above, given the gradient of the covariance function?

**Q2.** How can one obtain these predictions using the GPML toolbox (if at all possible)?

Comment: have you found your answer how to do this? Or did you find that you just don't need it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with a note: you call X matrix of "coordinates"; these are rather covariates, in general.

Next, you came to the $\partial_i K(X_*, X) K(X,X)^{-1} f$, which seems correct. But in the further text you are just considering the derivation of $K$, while you still need the derivation of $K^{-1}$ and $f$ as well, which I guess will be much more complicated.

So the answer to Q1 is NO, you are still missing much more pieces of the equation.

Regarding the Q2 and the $\partial K \over \partial x_i$ (i.e. your $\partial_i k(x,x')$) ... first, I cannot wrap my head around this, it seems like there is some principial problem there... since when you derive $k(x,x')$ by $x$ then by which $x$: $x$ or $x'$? Second, I am not user of `gpml` and matlab, but every GP software package needs to have  implemented $\partial K \over \partial l_i$ (you can e.g. see the [R implementation here](https://github.com/goldingn/GRaF/blob/master/R/cov.SE.d1.R)) but I doubt it has implemented the $\partial K \over \partial x_i$, because of the difficulties I mentioned in the previous points.

**EDIT: Q2: I actually found the computation of $\partial K \over \partial x_i$ !** Not in GPML, but in another Matlab software, [GPstuff: see function `gpcf_exp_ginput()`](https://github.com/gpstuff-dev/gpstuff/blob/master/gp/gpcf_exp.m):

```
%    DKff = GPCF_EXP_GINPUT(GPCF, X) takes a covariance function
%    structure GPCF, a matrix X of input vectors and returns
%    DKff, the gradients of covariance matrix Kff = k(X,X) with
%    respect to X (cell array with matrix elements). This subfunction
%    is needed when computing gradients with respect to inducing
%    inputs in sparse approximations.
```